# Java create a sorted ArrayList Array from an ArrayList

Tags: java

I am trying to create an ArrayList Array from an existing ArrayList which contains all items from the ArrayList but sorted by the projectname in array of the ArrayList.
Here a visualization of my problem:

```
ArrayList<Data>:
[String name0, ...]
[String name0, ...]
[String name1, ...]
[String name0, ...]
[String name1, ...]
...

->

ArrayList<ArrayList<Data>>:
0. ArrayList:        1. ArrayList:        ...
[String name0, ...]  [String name1, ...]
[String name0, ...]  [String name1, ...]
[String name0, ...]
...                  ...
```

Here is what I have already done:

```java
private ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Data>> separatedData = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> projectnames = new ArrayList<>();
private DataManager dataManager;

    public void GenerateDataArrays() throws IOException {

        //adds value to allData
        allData = dataManager.ReadData("data.csv");

        //get all project names out of the ArrayList and adds it to the 
        List projectnames
        for (Data data : allData) {
            if (!projectnames.contains(data.getProject())) {
                projectnames.add(data.getProject());
            }
        }

        //init new temporary ArrayList
        ArrayList<Data> pList = new ArrayList<>();

        //clears seperatedData because the method is called everytime a 
        //button is pressed to reload all data
        separatedData.clear();

        //looks for all Arrays in the Arraylist with the same name and 
        //adds each with an equal name to same list
        for (String name : projectnames) {
            pList.clear();
            for(Data data : allData){
                if (data.getProject().equals(name)){
                    pList.add(data);

                }
            }
            seperatedData.add(pList);

        }
    }
```

Where dataManager just reads a CSV file that looks like this:

```
"name","boolean1","amount","boolean2","date1","date2","date3","shop","reason","person","boolean3"
"SampleName","false","90.0","true","29.04.2019","29.04.2019","29.04.2019","Sampleshop","SampleReason","SamplePerson","true"
"SampleName","false","10.0","false","29.04.2019","29.04.2019","29.04.2019","Sampleshop","SampleReason","SamplePerson","true"
"SampleName2","false","90.0","false","29.04.2019","29.04.2019","29.04.2019","Sampleshop2","SampleReason2","SamplePerson2","true"
"LastProject","false","90.0","false","29.04.2019","29.04.2019","29.04.2019","Sampleshop","SampleReason","SamplePerson","true"
"LastProject","false","60.0","false","29.04.2019","29.04.2019","29.04.2019","Sampleshop","SampleReason","SamplePerson","true"
```

and adds it to an ArrayList which is returned by ReadData().

But when I call ArrayList Array 'separatedData' to recieve the 'names' and 'amount' for each 'Data' by doing this:

```
        for (ArrayList<Data> dataAll : separatedData){
            for(Data data : dataAll){
                    System.out.println(data.getProject() + ", " + data.getAmount());
            }
        }
```

I recieve this:

```
LastProject, 90.0
LastProject, 60.0
LastProject, 90.0
LastProject, 60.0
LastProject, 90.0
LastProject, 60.0
```

which is 1. only the latest added project and 2. thrice of the initial amount (The ArrayList allData is fine)

Comment: Instead of `pList.clear();`, use `pList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @BlackPearl that just fixed it. But why does this work and not clear()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here :

```
ArrayList<Data> pList = new ArrayList<>();
separatedData.clear();
for (String name : projectnames) {
   pList.clear();
   for(Data data : allData){
        if (data.getProject().equals(name)){
             pList.add(data);

        }
    }
    seperatedData.add(pList);

}
```

You create just one `ArrayList`  referenced by `plist` and you are constantly clearing the same `ArrayList` in your for loop. Moreover you add the same reference to `ArrayList` to your `separatedData`. In the end you have `ArrayList` containg multiple references to the same `ArrayList`.
As suggested by @BlackPearl the solution is to create a new list in your for loop every time :

```
for (String name : projectnames) {
        ArrayList<Data> pList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Data data : allData){
            if (data.getProject().equals(name)){
                pList.add(data);
            }
        }
        seperatedData.add(pList);

}
```